# Crashlytics (Fabric App) Causes Codesign Failure (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

I am trying to update our application today, and Crashlytics is causing code signing to fail upon submission to the app store.

The log says that the fabric.app is the culprit, any ideas?

Here is the error
[image]

Here is my prov profile.
[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here, I sent you an email, but getting your logs would help us get to the bottom of this!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to my comment, make sure that you don't have Fabric.app copied or linked into your app. Remove that copy or link and only link in the frameworks.